# Mapping geopoint doesn't work in ElasticSearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, geopoints

I'm using [NodeJS ElasticSearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js) with ElasticSearch 7.0. I create mapping `geo_point` type on specific field, but it doesn't show geo_point type in `_mapping`. I tried to search using `filter.geo_distance`, I got `failed to find geo point field`.

**Node ElasticSearch Mapping**

```
client.indices.putMapping({
  index: 'listing',
  type: 'detail',
  body: {
    properties: {
      'listing_coordinates': {
        "type": "geo_point"
      }
    }
  }
}, function(err) { console.log(err) })
```

**Mapping Error**

> [illegal_argument_exception] Types cannot be provided in put mapping
>   requests, unless the include_type_name parameter is set to true.

**/listing/_mapping**

```
mappings: {
 properties: {
  "listing_coordinates": {
    "properties": {
      "lat": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "lon": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
 }
}
```

**Node Search**

```
client.search({
    index: 'listing',
    type: 'detail',
    size: 5,
    body: {
      query : {
        "bool": {
          "filter": {
            "geo_distance" : {
              "distance" : "500km",
              "listing_coordinates" : {
                "lat" : 3.0567521,
                "lon" : 101.5854671
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
 }
```

**Search error**

> [query_shard_exception] failed to find geo_point field
>   [listing_coordinates]

I had mapping dates fields on my listing, it worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/issues/166
I think your problem should be similar to his. Please pay attention to the order of event execution. Also note that if you did not wait for PutMapping to be finished, then those index might be created automatically into text fields.

**Update:**

It seemed that your PutMapping failed and then your mapping is created into text field by receiving data as default behavior.

In ES7.0, you cannot provide type when creating an index unless setting `include_type_name`. In your case, type is `detail`. To handle `include_type_name`, see [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/removal-of-types.html#_typeless_apis_in_7_0). Or you could just try to remove `type: detail` in your case. Please try to clear your index mapping before trying.

Ref:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/removal-of-types.html#removal-of-types

Comment: I checked the order. Everything is fine. I add callback for `putMapping` method and I receive an error. `[illegal_argument_exception] Types cannot be provided in put mapping requests, unless the include_type_name parameter is set to true.`

Comment: Yep. This is the problem. Will Update my answer.

Comment: @Fei : i have add **options.typeName+"?Finclude_type_name=true";** it is give same error any idea? my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57325097/include-type-name-parameter-is-set-to-true-in-node-js